# django uwsgi error python application not found after set databases?

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I found in my project, django will give me this words"uwsgi error python application not found".

django project file tree

- /home
- -/home/imagepro
- -/home/imagepro/env #virtualenv
- -/home/imagepro/picpro #django project
- -/home/imagepro/picpro/picapp #django application
- -/home/imagepro/picpro/picpro

my uwsgi setting, file named pic.ini

```
[uwsgi]
vhost = true
plugins = python
socket = /tmp/pic.sock
master = true
enable-threads = true
processes = 4
wsgi-file = /home/imagepro/picpro/picpro/wsgi.py
virtualenv = /home/imagepro/env
chdir = /home/imagepro/picpro
touch-reload = /home/imagepro/picpro/reload
```

my nginx setting,file named pic

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    root /home/imagepro;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/imagepro.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/imagepro.error.log;
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  unix:///tmp/pic.sock;
        include     uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

piece of django setings.py

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
......#here DATABASE setting
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Here DATABASES setting, when note it, visit 'www.mydomain.com', It shows 'It works!' ,but if I add the DATABASES into settings.py . visit 'www.mydomain.com', It shows 'uwsgi error python application not found'

It's very strange,how could I fix it?

Comment: One way to fix this, is to enable the database setting, and then try a management command, like `python manage.py migrate` (from the shell) and see what the error is.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid，Great！It works, It seems like no mater with pic.ini